# Was woundering if there was a way to have a JUnit class that runs other JUnit testclasses

Tags: java, junit4

Was woundering if there was a way to have a JUnit class that runs other JUnit testclasses.
I have got a few testclasses, and i wan't to make a JUnit class that runs all the other test classes so i can just run the one JUnit class to run all the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need a TestSuite.

http://junit.sourceforge.net/junit3.8.1/javadoc/junit/framework/TestSuite.html